# How to find screen workarea on Wayland?

Tags: linux, screen, wayland

I need to find workareas of multiple screens on Wayland. When my application run on Xorg, I can find it by watching on _GTK_WORKAREAS_D0 property of root window on GNOME 3.36+, or by searching panel windows (which has _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK type) on Plasma, or by finding windows with same size as workareas (which has _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP type) on Cinnamon.

Unfortunately, there are not _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK windows on Plasma (I tried this on openSUSE 15.2 with Plasma Wayland + Xwayland), nor _GTK_WORKAREAS_D0 property of root window on GNOME (I tried this on CentOS 8 Stream + GNOME Wayland + Xwayland). I didn't try Cinnamon+Wayland because have not one, but I'm pretty sure that this will not work anyway (but maybe I'm wrong).

As far as I know, there is no way find any Wayland native windows (because of security reasons), so I cannot find any panel window there.

I still can watch on _NET_WORKAREA property of root window, but it works bad with multiple screens. Is there any way to find screen workarea on Wayland (if possible - which works both on GNOME and Plasma)?